# TypeScript. Как указать, что длина массива больше чем 1

Tags: typescript

Есть функция

```
const foo = (...args: number[]) => {
    args.reduce((acc, num) => {
        // some operation
        return acc;
    });
};
```

Вызов `foo()` без аргументов будет являться корректным. Возник вопрос, а как сделать так, чтобы TS проверял, что длина ...args будет 1 или больше?

Если кто знает напишите. Спасибо

Comment: @AlexanderChernin мне нужно отследить ошибку на этапе синтаксического анализа кода при написании а не во время выполнения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
const foo = (...args: [number, ...number[]]) => {
    args.reduce((acc, num) => {
        // some operation
        return acc;
    });
};
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо))